# Securely use other Firebase services in a Firebase Hosting app

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I'm developing an idea and I just started trying out Authentication.
All of the other Firebase services I want to use require API key that needs to be added to the site. Specifically, following the Authentication example: it's pasted in the login form itself.

[Following the Authentication example, this would be visible when pressing CTRL+U.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ce9nd.png)

When I check the code on a browser, the API key is obviously visible which I think is pretty dangerous. Is there any way to do these kinds of things securely when hosting your app on Firebase Hosting?

Comment: Exposing the API key is *not* a security risk. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482366/what-is-the-firebase-apikey-for

Comment: Thank you! Guess my search wasn't thorough enough!